# Xbox Music RESTful API on Azure access problems

Tags: c#, javascript, rest, azure, xbox-music

The simple goal here is to access the Xbox Music RESTful API on Azure and I stumble on the first part of it which is getting the Access Token. By following this procedure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546686.aspx it's simply not allowing me to get a token.

Thus far I have:

- I have a datamarket registration
- I registered an application, got a client_id and client_secret
- Subscribed to the Xbox Music RESTful API

Then I simply try to get a token either through a POST using XMLHttpRequest or Advanced Rest Client for Chrome and thus far all I receive is this Json response:

```
{
    "error":"invalid_client",
    "error_description":"ACS50012: Authentication failed.\r\nTrace ID: d2469189-d620-4725-98c6-544e3899d711\r\nCorrelation ID: 3726a6c7-de19-4873-a90c-b51c7ca447a7\r\nTimestamp: 2014-05-08 14:18:31Z"
}
```

I did some research for this error here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg429787.aspx but can't seem to pull an explanation for this.

The data explorer is also broken as I receive this:

```
The request resulted in a backend time out or backend error. The team is investigating the issue. We are sorry for the inconvenience. (502)
```

In the end I assume something is bogus with my account but can't figure it out. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got it resolved. Recreating the application and getting a new client_secret fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

See comment, recreate a new application and copy client secret properly.